# Set the size for a sprite image position within a background

Tags: css, background-image

I'm positioning a small image in the corner of the background of a div. I want to include it in a sprite but I'm not sure how to set the size of the image from the sprite. My only solution I can think of is to place the image on the absolute bottom right corner of the sprite to force the size. A better solution. Here's the CSS so far:

```css
background: url(images/fod-sprite.png) 99% 99% no-repeat #000;
background-position: -4px -154px;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't do this. Just don't use a spritesheet.

Comment: The sprite needs to be the same size as the containing element or you'll need to add white-space to the sprite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the img within a span that's absolutely positioned, affix it to the lower right, then use the clip property to set the size from the sprite.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bengundersen/BSswy/

Edit: You can do this without the span as long as overflow is set on the parent div.

Another benefit of using a clipped img is that you can still print.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `:before` pseudo-class:

```
.test:before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  width: 16px; /* requires width */
  height: 16px; /* require height */
  margin: 0 5px 0 0; /* specify margin */
  background: #000 url(images/fod-sprite.png) -4px -154px no-repeat;
}
```